# How to scan static copy of website for evidence of being hacked

Tags: javascript, html, security, drupal

I need to review a Drupal site in order to determine if it has been potentially been compromised as a result of SA-CORE-2014-005 (Drupageddon) vulnerability. I have a set of procedures I plan to follow, which I obtained from another website:

- Check files integrity for changes using Git status or if not possible using Hacked
- Scan public / private files locations for *.php, *.sh and any other suspicious files.
- Check file ownership and permissions on site
- Install and run Drupalgeddon module
- Install and run Security Review module
- Install and run Site Audit module
- Review MySQL and webserver logs
- Check users to find if any have ‘admin’ role when they shouldn't.
- Check roles  to find if any have altered permissions, or any new ones have  been created.
- Check users table for suspicious entries
- Check menu_router table for suspicious entries
- Check overridden features for suspicious changes
- Review any content using HTML input filters for suspicious content.
- Review variable table to find any suspicious values
- If possible analyse sessions table for logins of admin/advanced users from external IP addresses and check their last login dates
- Dump the entire website HTML, e.g. using some crawler, and grep for additional parameters in links
- Check database for any new MySQL users.

One of the steps is to

> Dump the entire website HTML, e.g. using some crawler, and grep for additional parameters in links

I was planning on dumping the site using `wget -r -k -l0 website-uri`.  What I am not sure about is what kind of things am I looking for? How would I go about grepping for these? Is there some tool that can do this already?

Answer (score 0):

About Ways to Dump or GREP:

- Database: Using Sequel Pro/PhpMyAdmin you can dump a .sql of the entire database and then can find via textedit etc if you know what you are looking for. You can also do direct comparisons this way between two database dump to look for before and after scenarios.

Using [Drush](http://www.drushcommands.com/):
A lot of your tasks can be handled via Drush. If you do not know or have not used it then highly recommend finding more about it and using it.

What to look for:

- One of the key things I see missing from your list is logs. One of the first places to look is under Drupal Watchdog and server logs. These serve as good indicators of any suspicious activity (in a ton of messages ofcourse) as well as a good snapshot of what was happening at certain times.
- Narrowing down the time for which you are looking or know the attack may have caused problems would help you look at a smaller subset of logs
- Remember though that some of the compromises are beyond just code. For e.g. someone gaining an admin access and changing a piece of content. That is really hard to separate from the regular site behavior of site admin or editors updating content. Thus everything would depend on the definition of compromise that the stake holders and the site would define as.